# Installing Mint and completely removing Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, grub2, mint

I was able to successfully install Ubuntu along with Windows using boot repair. Now I've decided to betray ubuntu and start using Mint. So I want to install Mint and completely **remove** Ubuntu. I don't want to touch Windows.

Is it possible? Does it have to do with boot repair? I should first install Mint and then remove Ubuntu, correct?

Comment: Just install it over Ubuntu.

Comment: @Seth, what do you mean by over? To override (replace) it with Mint?

Comment: yes override it with mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply install Mint over the Ubuntu partitions. The installation will wipe the partitions and install Mint on it.

Comment: all my documents, downloads, etc will be erased, right?

Comment: Yes they will, it will erase previous installation.